# How do you link two models ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

currently I have this two models:

Contact.cs

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ConctactId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

PhoneNumber.cs

```
 public class PhoneNumber
{
    public int PhoneNumberId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public PhoneNumberTypeEnum EnumType { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, what is a correct way to alter these two so I can have multiple instances of PhoneNumber linked to one Contact? Also, later I would like to display all contacts in View with corresponding phone numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your models as following

```
public class Contact
{
    public int ConctactId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PhoneNumber> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class PhoneNumber
{
    public int PhoneNumberId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public PhoneNumberTypeEnum EnumType { get; set; }

    public int ContactId {get; set;}

    public virtual Contact Contact{get; set;}
}
```

Comment: you don't need to use virtual in .NET Core

Comment: Thank you very much, this was helpful. I just have one question.. Why do I need Contact property in PhoneNumber model?

Comment: This property is optional, but as object oriented aspect is need, also when use entity framework this field needed for join and eager loading